# simulating html errors for ajax

Tags: ajax, testing

I have found this nifty little script as to how to simulate http network delays for ajax
http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/1768

Is there a way to extend this method to make the AJAX call receive a "server not found" error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this by overriding the open() function and purposely messing up the URL. This causes the original send function to return an error. Combining both solutions you can also get delayed errors.